# Что делает строка ans^=x, прилагаю задачу и код

Tags: c++, битовые-операции, xor

Объясните фрагмент `ans^=x`.

Для массива целых чисел, где все элементы, кроме одного, встречаются дважды, найдите уникальный элемент.

**Пример:**
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
Уникальный элемент - `4`

```
int lonelyinteger(vector<int> a) {
    int ans=0;
    for(auto x:a) ans^=x;
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`^`, как вы справедливо заметили в метках — операция xor.

А запись `a @= b` означает `a = a @ b`, т.е.

```
ans ^= x;
```

означает

```
ans = ans ^ x;
```

Если же вопрос о *смысле* сего действа, то заметим, что после двух xor с одним и тем же числом мы получаем исходное значение:

```
a ^ x ^ x == a
```

Дальше понятно, почему это делается? :)

P.S. Картинками здесь вопросы задавать **крайне** не рекомендуется...

Comment: Все в порядке, я подправил его вопрос, только примите правку

Comment: @Harry Я бы решил эту задачу так: int lonelyinteger(vector<int> a) {
sort(a.begin(), a.end());
int i = 0;
for (; i < a.size(); i+=2)
if (a[i] != a[i+1])
break;
return a[i];
}   ранее не сталкивался с xor и подобными сокращенными циклами for, можно поподробнее разжевать?

Comment: @Bukashka битовые операции очень эффективные, они позволяют сократить работу кода в несколько раз, но тогда уж если вы паритесь над скоростью, то без векторов, и for_each //(for auto - цикл где перебираются элементы массива, где x == a[i] при обыкновенном переборе). Скорее задача не требует такой выходки достаточно простенького решения за O(n) O(nlogn), что и вы предложили с помощью сортировки, можно также map- ом решить

Comment: Сокращенный цикл — по сути, ` for(auto x:a) ans^=x;` то же, что `for(auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it) { x = *it; ans^=x; }`. То, что предлагаете вы, имеет сложность O(n*log n) (из-за сортировки)? этот же алгоритм - O(n) с *очень* малой константой.

Comment: @Harry у нас x это индекс значения вектора (или можно интерпритировать как a[x] ?), исходя из этого, не разберусь, как функция вовзращает именно элемент одиночку. Даже если a ^^ = a, тогда должно возввращать последний осмотренный элемент a (по примеру 1) и это если рассматривать как x - элемент вектора. Немного запутался.

Comment: x - это **элемент** вектора.

Comment: @Harry можете на примере расписать?

Comment: 2 2 3. 0 xor 2 = 2. 2 xor 2 = 0. 0 xor 3 = 3.